# Is power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$ uniformly convergent in $(-1,1)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I know that if $\sum a_nx^n$ has radius of convergence R then this power series converges uniformly for every compact subset of $(-R,R)$ and now no doubt converges pointwise in $(-R,R)$ but little bit confused what can we say about uniform convergence in $(-R,R)$.

As for example what can we say about uniform convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$ in (-1,1)?

Comment: Compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}\sum_{k=n}^{k=2n} {x^k\over k}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Any partial sum is bounded, but the series converges pointwise to something unbounded.

Comment: can you please elaborate more, I don't understand your hint

Comment: @Ibs For any natural $N$, the function $x\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^N\frac{x^n}{n}$ is bounded on $(-1,1)$. But the function $x\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}$ is unbounded. Show that a sequence of bounded functions can't converge uniformly to an unbounded function.

Comment: (deleted my other comment, nevermind, forgot the compactness hypothesis on Stone-Weierstraß :/)

Comment: @arthur is the uniform limit bounded?do you mean this?never mind I am new to this subject.

Comment: @Ibs If a sequence converges uniformly, then the uniform limit is the same as the pointwise limit. So you don't need to specify "the uniform limit" or "the pointwise limit". There is just "the limit". And in this case we can show, without too much effort, that the limit is unbounded. With a little more effort, we can show that if it converges uniformly, then the limit is bounded. From these two facts we can easily conclude that the sequence can't converge uniformly.

Comment: @arthur actually I have a doubt,can I say that **for a power series$\sum a_nx^n$ having radius of convergence R,if series doesn't not converges at end points R and -R then it doesn't converges uniformly on (-R,R)** is this statement correct? If not then please provide me a counter example to discard it

Comment: @Ibs The argument I have hinted at here works to show there is no uniform convergence as long as the series fails to converge at either $R$ or at $-R$. I don't know, off the top of my head, any series that converges _at_ the boundary of convergence. But I don't know that none exist.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a mostly painless way to show unboundedness, in order to apply Arthur's hint.

As you note $s = \sum_j x^j/j$ converges over compact sets, and moreover so does the series of term-wise derivatives $\sum_{j \geq 1}x^{j-1} = \sum_{j \geq 0}x^j = 1/(1-x)$. A standard theorem of series gives $s' = 1/(1-x)$ and so integrating and using that $s(0) = 0$ one gets

$$
s(x) = -\mathbf{ln}(1-x)
$$

and then $s(x) \xrightarrow{x \to _+1} +\infty$.

Comment: I prefer to note that on $[-1,1]$, any partial sum of the series is continuous. And we know that at $1$, the partial sums grow without bound. But this ought to work too.

Answer (score 2):

If it is uniformly convergent then there exists $m$ such that $ |\sum\limits_{k=i}^{j}\frac {x^{k}} k| <1$ for all $x$ for all $j>i>m$. Let $x \to 1$ in this. Do you see a contradiction?

Comment: @Kavuramamurthy actually I have a doubt,can I say that **for a power series $\sum a_nx^n$ having radius of convergence R,if series doesn't not converges at end points R and -R then it doesn't converges uniformly on (-R,R)** is this statement correct? If not then please provide me a counter example to discard it

Comment: That is a corrrect statement. There is no counter-example. @Ibs

Comment: thanks a lot sir!